# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Using node, express, socket.io, jade and angular. Getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. Any suggestions?

index.js:

```
module.exports = function(app, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  var io = app.get('io');
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
  });
};
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content

script.
    var app = angular.module('hackigur', []);
    var socket = io.connect();
    var refreshTimer = 10;

    app.controller('UpdateController', function($scope){
        //socket.on('update', function(msg){
            //$scope.refreshTimer = msg;
            //$scope.$apply();
        //});

        setInterval(secondTick,1000);

        function secondTick() {
            if(refreshTimer != 0) {
                refreshTimer -= 1;
            }
            $scope.refreshTimer = refreshTimer;
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    });

h1= title
p Welcome to #{title}

div(ng-controller="UpdateController")
    p(ng-bind="refreshTimer")
```

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="hackigur")
  head
    title= title
    script(src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src = "/js/angular/angular.min.js")
  body
    block content
```

Full error:

```
Server listening on port 3000
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Server.(anonymous function) [as on] (D:\Projects\hackigur\node_modules\so
cket.io\lib\index.js:364:15)
    at module.exports (D:\Projects\hackigur\server\api\index.js:30:8) at ...
```

Comment: FYI index.js:30 is the line: io.on('connection', function(socket){ ... this code actually worked last night and I tried again tonight and it died.

Comment: Could you please post the entirety of index.js?  It seems errors are happening on lines you don't include in this question.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you have multiple index.js's (my bad).  Could you at least clarify which index.js you have provided?

Comment: there's only one index.js... the other is index.jade. i've posted pretty much the entire index.js above; the remainder is just a large function that i've completely commented out

Comment: index.js I posted is the server/api/index.js; the other socket.io one I didn't touch, it's whatever npm installed in node_modules for socket.io

Comment: I know very little Jade, but just to clarify:  why is there a period after "script" in the first line of the main block in index.jade?

Comment: That's Jade's way of saying "everything indented below this belongs to this tag". Fairly certain this is some socketio error, but I can't for the life of me figure it out

Comment: What version of `socket.io` do you have installed (you can check with `npm ls`)? Also, where do you `app.set('io', ...)` and create the `socket.io` server instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My `router` which called my `index.js` passed `app` in the `module.export` as such:

```
module.export = function (app) {
    app.get( ... , function(..., res) { 
        require(index.js)(app)(res);
};
```

I needed to declare a variable for `app` external to my `module.export`:

```
var x;
module.export = function (app) {
    x = app;
        app.get( ... , function(..., res) { 
        require(index.js)(x)(res);
};
```

Don't fully understand why it worked, but it seemed to pass the correct `app` object to `app.get` by applying the above.